# Better way to create database for a pricing system

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, database-design

I need to create a price table system so I am going to create these three tables in my database.

- PricingTable `(ID, Name, ServiceID, Style)`
- PricingTablePackages `(ID, PricingTable_ID, Title, Price, PricePerTime, Info, Flag, Link)`
- PricingTablePackagesFeatures `(ID, PricingTablePackages_ID, Feature, Value, MoreInfo)`

Here one `PriceTable` can hold more then one `PricingTablePackages` and one `PricingTablePackage` can hold more then one `PricingTablePackagesFeature`.

Is any way to design a better model? In a single database Table ?

I am going to create a MVC3 Model for those table so what is the best way to do this kind of DB Table in a MVC3 Model?

Comment: Well I don't see any problems so far.. if what you want to do with the tables is all described there..It should be fine.

Comment: i did that table but i thought if there was any more good idea :) OK i am going to apply that, thank u for your comments :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use public virtual variables for 'lazy-loading' values when you need them using Entity Framework:

(variable types may be off depending on exactly what you want for each variable)

```
public class PricingTablePackages
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int PricingTableID { get; set; }

    public virtual PricingTable PricingTable { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public decimal PricePerTime { get; set; }

    public string Info { get; set; }

    public bool Flag { get; set; }

    public string Link { get; set; }
}

public class PricingTablePackagesFeatures
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int PricingTableID { get; set; }

    public virtual PricingTable PricingTable { get; set; }

    public string Feature { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public string MoreInfo { get; set; }
}

public class PricingTable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ServiceID { get; set; }

    public virtual Service Service { get; set; } // if there is a Service class

    public string Style { get; set; }
}
```